# How to get the text inside a label tag on a click event in ReactJs?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to get the text inside the label tag on a click event of the label. Here is my code.

```
import React from 'react';

class Todo extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.handleOnClick = this.handleOnClick.bind(this);
    }

    handleOnClick(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        console.log(e.target.value);
        this.props.onToggle(e.target.value);
    }

    render() {
        return (<div>
                            <label onClick={this.handleOnClick}>{this.props.taskName}</label>
                            <button>Edit</button>
                            <button>Delete</button>
                        </div>);
    }
}

module.exports = Todo;
```

But in the console log in getting undefined. Can anyone tell me what should be right way to get this value.

Comment: `<label>` elements don't have `value` so you can't use `e.target.value`

Comment: wouldn't the text be `this.props.taskName`?

Comment: @Dekel then what is the correct way.

Comment: I don't know what you are trying to do and what is the value you are trying to get so I can't have the "right way" for you here

Comment: @FuzzyTree but I want it get through the event object

Comment: I am actually sending it to its parent component to do some other processing

Comment: Since it came from the parent, why are you trying to send it back to parent?

Comment: I am actually creating a todo app. The parent is going to have a list of todos and I need to get the specific todo to manage further actions.

Comment: You can just do `this.props.onToggle(this.props.taskName);` but since both of them coming from the parent component it seems a bit long way to me.

Answer (score 0):

Only input fields have values, a label doesn't have it.

The value won't be in the event object, so you have to do it a different way:

```
<label onClick={() => this.handleLabelClick(this.props.taskName)}>
  {this.props.taskName}
</label>
```

`handleLabelClick` will have the task name as the parameter.

Comment: You can avoid IIFE and pass params with binding onClick={this.handleOnClick.bind(this, this.props.taskName)}